# Какие dll добавить в проект Qt, чтобы на удаленном компьютере работал доступ к MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Добрый день.
Пишу приложение на `Qt`, в котором использую `MySQL`. Пока запускаю у себя на компьютере, все работает, как только создаю проект и скидываю его коллеге, перестают обнаруживаться драйвера к `MySQL`. Пробовал и вручную закидывать нужные `dll` в папку, и собирать с помощью `Windows Deployment Tool`, но все без изменений... Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: Плагины Qt (qsqlmysql.dll) рядом с исполняемым файлом лежат?

Comment: @ixSci нет в папке `sqlplugins`, спасибо, я уже решил проблему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего не хватает libmySQL.dll для работы драйвера QMYSQL. Сам файл можно взять в каталоге программы MySQL.

Comment: Пробовал. Пихал и в корневую папку и в `sqldrivers`. Все также...

Comment: Скинул dll'ку установленной на сервере MySQL 5.7x64 - заработало...
Хотя у меня работает с MySQL 5.5x32... чудеса... Дело, верно, в том, что версия драйверов тоже x64 и компилю MSVC17x64... Ладно, спасибо вам.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю свое РЕШЕНИЕ ПРОБЛЕМЫ.

При переносе  релиза приложения Qt с MySql на др. компьютер и попытке запуска, выдавалось: SQL DRIVER NOT LOADED. Сейчас все РАБОТАЕТ. Как достиг этого:
1. В папке релиза, рядом с exe-шником, должна располагаться папка sqldrivers c файлом qsqlmysql.dll. Этот файл брал из:  Пусть_установки_Qt\5.12.0\mingw73_64\plugins\sqldrivers

2. В папке релиза, рядом с exe-шником, должен лежать файл libmysql.dll. Этот файл брал из: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib
3. В папке релиза, рядом с exe-шником, должны лежать файлы libeay32.dll и ssleay32.dll. Эти файлы брал из:  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin

Только при обязательном выполнении этих трех пунктов. Приложение - релиз, запускаемое на другом компе, нормально подключалось к Базе данных mysql.

Был потрачен день на поиск решения (на форумах много советов, но этого я не нашел в свое время). Надеюсь, кому-то пригодится!